# TypeScript 2.6 incorrectly expanding this type used as generic parameter

Tags: typescript, generics, this

I'm having a slightly complex issue with the use of the `this` type with generic interfaces in TypeScript 2.6. It seems to work fine in 2.5. Consider the following:

```
interface EntitySet<T> {
    promise: Promise<this>;
}

class SetInfo<TEntity, SetType extends EntitySet<TEntity>> { }

export class AnEntitySet<TEntity> implements EntitySet<TEntity> {
    promise = new Promise<this>(r => { });
    fails = new SetInfo<TEntity, this>();
    //                           ^--- Error here
    works: EntitySet<TEntity> = this
}
```

It fails to compile with the following error:

```
Type 'this' does not satisfy the constraint 'EntitySet<TEntity>'.
  Type 'AnEntitySet<TEntity>' is not assignable to type 'EntitySet<TEntity>'.
    Types of property 'promise' are incompatible.
      Type 'Promise<AnEntitySet<TEntity>>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<this>'.
        Type 'AnEntitySet<TEntity>' is not assignable to type 'this'.
```

On the surface, the message `Type 'AnEntitySet<TEntity>' is not assignable to type 'EntitySet<TEntity>'` seems patently wrong. Of course `AnEntitySet<TEntity>` is assignable to `EntitySet<TEntity>`, it directly implements it! And, of course, I can assign `this` to a field of type `EntitySet<TEntity>` just fine (see the `works` field).

It seems that somehow the `this` type is being expanded to `AnEntitySet<TEntity>` somewhere, which is indeed not assignable to `this` since the `this` might be some subclass. But in this case, all type specifiers refer to `this`, so that seems invalid.

Is this a regression in TypeScript's handling of the `this` type? Was it broken before and is now working as designed? Is there an easy workaround? It seems like bug to me.

Comment: After doing some more research, I _think_ this issue is related to https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21117